# AWS ECS containers restarting randomly

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, amazon-ecs

I have certain spring boot (**V1.5.10**) containers running on an AWS ECS cluster consisting of two EC2 instances (ECS Agent **V1.33.0** and docker **V18.06.1-ce**).

These services are load-balanced and for the past week, I am facing this issue where certain containers randomly restart, causing their corresponding tasks to terminate. The containers run for around 1-2 hours and they restart.

I have checked the logs for ECS services, there are no helpful logs, just the ones regarding deregistering and restart of the services.

When I check the tasks in a service, it shows an **`Essential container in the task stopped`** error and no other information.

I have checked the docker containers on the EC2 instances using `docker ps -a` and they show exited `Exited (1) 14 minutes ago` and so on.

I have checked the logs for the ecs-agent as well, but there is no clear reason regarding the restart in them.

Sometimes, the docker daemon stops working as well and commands like **`docker ps`** don't work.

These are some of the logs from the ecs agent

```
fb1e9358d2cb2f20f481e9ef222503acf5f75090b8 <nil> [] <nil> [{volume d1f29eb945fd5e670e17e370af28cfbd7cac1c35f74dec56dc42fc5f58691d7c /var/lib/docker/volumes/d1f29eb945fd5e670e17e370af28cfbd7cac1c35f74dec56dc42fc5f58691d7c/_data /tmp13 local  true }] map[com.amazonaws.ecs.cluster:Test com.amazonaws.ecs.container-name:app1 com.amazonaws.ecs.task-arn:arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:7879097520:task/Test/2d1b6e48fe6748439fad2549de847af1 com.amazonaws.ecs.task-definition-family:Test-App1 com.amazonaws.ecs.task-definition-version:2] 2020-12-02 13:14:15.155236268 +0000 UTC 2020-12-02 13:14:15.693163539 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC {UNKNOWN <nil> 0 } bridge 0xc000b36e00} ContainerStatusChangeEvent}] for container [App1]
    2020-12-10T13:10:10Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:7879097520:task/Test/2d1b6e48fe6748439fad2549de847af1]: redundant container state change. App1 to RUNNING, but already RUNNING
    2020-12-10T13:10:10Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:7879097520:task/Test/2d1b6e48fe6748439fad2549de847af1]: task at steady state: RUNNING
    2020-12-10T13:10:10Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:7879097520:task/Test/2d1b6e48fe6748439fad2549de847af1]: waiting for event for task
    2020-12-10T13:10:59Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:7879097520:task/Test/1b767a28b694464ea82a65ae21f971cd]: no longer waiting
    2020-12-10T13:10:59Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:7879097520:task/Test/1b767a28b694464ea82a65ae21f971cd]: task at steady state: RUNNING
    2020-12-10T13:10:59Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:7879097520:task/Test/1b767a28b694464ea82a65ae21f971cd]: waiting for event for task
    2020-12-10T13:10:59Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:7879097520:task/Test/1b767a28b694464ea82a65ae21f971cd]: got container [tracking] event: [RUNNING]
    2020-12-10T13:10:59Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:7879097520:task/Test/1b767a28b694464ea82a65ae21f971cd]: handling container change [{RUNNING {52d5eaa86f865c1f7e8777fbb9b3368c96f927e0e215a8dda94703a47457dfa4 <nil> [{8081 57145 0.0.0.0 0}] <nil> [{volume 516048bf9205ee72b2b1f9226fa4827c897e853a7582e751fddf5a246d70f48e /var/lib/docker/volumes/516048bf9205ee72b2b1f9226fa4827c897e853a7582e751fddf5a246d70f48e/_data /tmp2 local  true }] map[com.amazonaws.ecs.cluster:Test com.amazonaws.ecs.container-name:tracking com.amazonaws.ecs.task-arn:arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:7879097520:task/Test/1b767a28b694464ea82a65ae21f971cd com.amazonaws.ecs.task-definition-family:Test-Tracking com.amazonaws.ecs.task-definition-version:2] 2020-12-10 12:10:58.810724617 +0000 UTC 2020-12-10 12:10:59.335518545 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC {UNKNOWN <nil> 0 } bridge 0xc000b5b100} ContainerStatusChangeEvent}] for container [tracking]
    2020-12-10T13:10:59Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:7879097520:task/Test/1b767a28b694464ea82a65ae21f971cd]: redundant container state change. tracking to RUNNING, but already RUNNING
    2020-12-10T13:10:59Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:7879097520:task/Test/1b767a28b694464ea82a65ae21f971cd]: task at steady state: RUNNING
    2020-12-10T13:10:59Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:7879097520:task/Test/1b767a28b694464ea82a65ae21f971cd]: waiting for event for task
    2020-12-10T13:12:37Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:7879097520:task/Test/e8d3302d694642999668484bc6f99f1b]: no longer waiting
    2020-12-10T13:12:37Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:7879097520:task/Test/e8d3302d694642999668484bc6f99f1b]: task at steady state: RUNNING
    2020-12-10T13:12:37Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:7879097520:task/Test/e8d3302d694642999668484bc6f99f1b]: waiting for event for task
    2020-12-10T13:12:37Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:7879097520:task/Test/e8d3302d694642999668484bc6f99f1b]: got container [inventory] event: [RUNNING]
    2020-12-10T13:12:37Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:7879097520:task/Test/e8d3302d694642999668484bc6f99f1b]: handling container change [{RUNNING {5df66bb5e4f563e48aee457310a862edff73f0df67f9c2a329bff0f910261731 <nil> [{10000 57132 0.0.0.0 0}] <nil> [{volume 0684429d8b825c08f26074f37ea0f23026eb500a5b0dca75213b56d22e4442d6 /var/lib/docker/volumes/0684429d8b825c08f26074f37ea0f23026eb500a5b0dca75213b56d22e4442d6/_data /tmp8 local  true }] map[com.amazonaws.ecs.cluster:Test com.amazonaws.ecs.container-name:inventory com.amazonaws.ecs.task-arn:arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:7879097520:task/Test/e8d3302d694642999668484bc6f99f1b com.amazonaws.ecs.task-definition-family:Test-Inventory com.amazonaws.ecs.task-definition-version:2] 2020-12-10 10:21:25.284497581 +0000 UTC 2020-12-10 10:21:26.56942361 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC {UNKNOWN <nil> 0 } bridge 0xc000b36700} ContainerStatusChangeEvent}] for container [inventory]
    2020-12-10T13:12:37Z [INFO] Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:7879097520:task/Test/e8d3302d694642999668484bc6f99f1b]: redundant container state change. inventory to RUNNING, but already RUNNING
```

I have a warning regarding the outdated ECS agent in my cluster. Could that be an issue?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like the process running in the Docker container is exiting. You might try enabling ECS Container Insights to get a better picture of the CPU and memory usage inside the container, but ultimately it sounds like you need to add more logging to the process to determine why it is exiting.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. In my case the it was to do with the Health Check timeout value in the Target Group. The timeout was set to 5 seconds, but sometimes it is longer responses are also accepted. I increased the timeout period to bigger value and it seems to have helped.
I understand that the Health Check path should be a fast endpoint, but in our specific application application several checks are needed and it can sometimes take longer than 5 seconds.
Just mentioning it here in case it helps someone.